# How do I separetly print two dictionary keys with the same value?

Tags: python, csv, file, dictionary, key

I want to print a message telling the user the most common personality type of an animal crossing villager using a dataset. However, the 'Lazy' and 'Normal' dictionary keys are both the most common and have the same value. I can't figure out how to make them print separately without hardcoding.

Here's my code:

```
totalfreq2 = {}

for p_type in personality:
  if p_type in totalfreq2:
    totalfreq2[p_type] +=1
  else:
    totalfreq2[p_type] = 1
print(totalfreq2)

maxfreq2 = max(totalfreq2.values())
print(maxfreq2)
toplst = ()
for p_type in totalfreq2:
  if totalfreq2[p_type] == 63:
    ww = p_type
print(ww)
print("The most common personality type for an Animal Crossing Villager is",ww,)
```

Here's the printed output:

```
{'Jock': 57, 'Cranky': 57, 'Peppy': 53, 'Big Sister': 26, 'Lazy': 63, 'Normal': 63, 'Snooty': 57, 'Smug': 37}
63
Normal
The most common personality type for an Animal Crossing Villager is Normal
```

How do I add 'Lazy' to this message without hardcoding?

Comment: That's not *all* your code.  Define `personality`.  It's best to post code that can be copied and run without changes to test it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had the right idea... just change toplist to an empty list and instead of assigning the value to the variable `ww` you can append the value to the list and then print the contents of the list once the loop has finished.

```
maxfreq2 = max(totalfreq2.values())
toplst = []
for p_type in totalfreq2:
  if totalfreq2[p_type] == maxfreq2:
    toplst.append(p_type)
print(toplst)
```

There are quite a few alternatives you could use as well.

list comprehension.

```
[print(i) for i in totalfreq2 if totalfreq2[i] == maxfreq2]
```

or you can use the filter function

```
for ptype in filter(lambda x: totalfreq2[x] == maxfreq2, totalfreq2.keys()):
    print(ptype)
```

Comment: Not going to work too well if the max value doesn't happen to be 63.

Comment: @MarkTolonen  Thanks for the tip I didn't realize that was even part of the question

Answer (score 0):

Collect all the keys that have the max value, then use `.join()` to print them nicely:

```py
# The missing data matching the OP's output.
personality = ['Jock'] * 57 + ['Cranky'] * 57 + ['Peppy'] * 53 + ['Big Sister'] * 26 + ['Lazy'] * 63 + ['Normal'] * 63 + ['Snooty'] * 57 + ['Smug'] * 37

totalfreq2 = {}

for p_type in personality:
  if p_type in totalfreq2:
    totalfreq2[p_type] +=1
  else:
    totalfreq2[p_type] = 1

maxfreq2 = max(totalfreq2.values())
# find all keys with same max value
toplist = [k for k,v in totalfreq2.items() if v == maxfreq2]
print(f"The most common personality type for an Animal Crossing Villager is: {', '.join(toplist)}")
```

Output:

```
The most common personality type for an Animal Crossing Villager is: Lazy, Normal
```

See also [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for a built-in way to count items and get the most common, for example:

```py
import collections
...
totalfreq2 = collections.Counter(personality)
# Returns counts sorted highest to lowest and gets the first one.
# It returns [(key, count)] hence the subscripting to get the count.
maxfreq2 = totalfreq2.most_common(1)[0][1]
...
```